# parallax scroll with image through logo transparency only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a div with a parallax effect. But i want the background to appear trought a transparent logo. I don't know how to explain in words, but this image is better to understand: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHPV9.jpg

The foreground img (dark-grey + trasparent logo) is where i'm trying to make it simple.
I could use a .png img but i want it to be responsive, this is why i'm doing this.

I already did it. It's working.

But i want to know if there is a better way to create this effect. When it comes to smaller viewports, like 320px width or something like this, the text bellow the logo doesn't appear, or the log get the bottom part cut out of the screen.

Here is a jsfiddle with the system working: (http://jsfiddle.net/zosrb445/)

Ps.: The extra background in this div:

```
<div class="hd-m-b">
```

is only weird in the jsfiddel file, in my local host it's everything normal.

Hope you guys can understand.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting position and z-index properties of your .hd-m-* divs.

```
.hd-m-m {position:fixed; z-index:10;} /*or position:absolute - as the need be */
.hd-m-t,
.hd-m-b { z-index:5; position:relative;}
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zosrb445/4/ (This should get you started; Not complete.)

Comment: Well, it's worse.. I don't think it's something with the position. Maybe it's with the height of the .hd-m-m element, but changing it's height is going to leave a blank space on the left/right side